# Is it possible to export geospatial PDF from QGIS via GDAL/OGR?

Tags: qgis, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

Is there any plugin for QGIS which would help me in exporting the map document as a geospatial PDF (similar to Terrago's GeoPDF)?