# Exporting QGIS Raster/Vector layers into one PDF?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, export, geopdf

I have seen a similiar post to this a while back ([Is it possible to export geospatial PDF from QGIS via GDAL/OGR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/is-it-possible-to-export-geopdf-from-qgis)), and thought I would try asking it again to see if there has been any improvement or new knowledge on this.

Is it possible to export one PDF with multiple layers like the picture shows?

[image: WMS with 4 seperate vector layers]

The above shows a Raster image (WMS) and 4 different Vector layers, is it possible to get all these into one PDF as different layers? As shown below, where you can click/unclick each layer?

[image: Layers in PDF]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Some of our protocols can take a little getting used to, and one to be aware of is that asking a question that has been asked before is frowned upon.  In particular, if you do mention an earlier question, then you should always include a link to it to make it easy for everyone to look back at it and decide whether they think it is a duplicate.