# Geospatial export to PDF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, maps, geospatial-pdf

I was wondering if someone can help me in the right direction to making a geospatial report. I used a drone to take aerial photos and used MME to stitch the photos together. I then uploaded the Geotiffs to QGIS with the Google Earth background, created a new print layout of the location map and exported the map to PDF. However, when I use the Geospatial Location Tool, the coordinates cannot be determined. I even tried to create a PDF from a .TIFF file and still no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded the Geotiffs to QGIS with the Google Earth background"? Also, what version of QGIS did you use? and what is MME?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find your answer in this link:
[Can QGIS export Geospatial PDF for Avenza PDF map app?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146602/can-qgis-export-geospatial-pdf-for-avenza-pdf-map-app)

Geo-referenced PDF's seem to be thoroughly discussed there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem why the coordinates were not able to be determined. I needed to change the map coordinates in QGIS to deg, min, sec instead of the map units(meters) default before I export to PDF.